# What do the profiling values mean on the minecraft debug screen?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What does each of the 10 parts shown on the Minecraft profiling graph mean?
[image]

Comment: They are right underneath it. Grey one is gameRenderer, and the blue display_update.

Comment: Yes, i know, but what do they represent. i know that render is the time that the game is using to render the world, but what are the rest?

Comment: I have a feeling they have something to do with the game's output log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information being covered up in the background is about your graphics card. If you increase the game resolution, or go into normal <kbd>F3</kbd> mode rather than <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> mode you should be able to see this.

The pie chart shows how long each different category of task has taken to complete in a frame. You can use the 1-9 keys to get a more detailed breakdown of each of these categories, and 0 to go back up a level.

I've searched around, including in the game code, to try to find out what each of the sections represent. I couldn't find a lot of definite answers, and a lot of it seems very temporary changing from version to version, so apologies for any mistakes:

- gameRenderer

Rendering of the game world and GUI. Fairly self evident, and supported by its sub-categories. Probably the one you should pay most attention for when aiming to reduce lag, as it's usually the biggest category.

- display_update

Used for VSync to prevent screen tearing. Should decrease if you turn VSync off in the options.

- tick

Processing in game ticks that occur 20 times a second. For example, melting ice.

- render

Seems to be rendering of things other than the game level and GUI. Jumps up when I open F3, so potentially also this pie chart.

- unspecified

Tasks not specified in the other sections on the pie chart. Any code not between a `mcProfiler.startSection("...")` and `mcProfiler.endSection()`.

- stream

Music, I think. Doesn't seem to use much percentage time even when music is playing though. I'm assuming this because in `sounds.json`, long sounds (records, ambient music) have `stream: true` to stream the sound from its file.

- sound

The sound engine playing normal sounds. Increases slightly when I burned a lot of zombies off at once.

- scheduledExecutables

Scheduled ticks. Used for things like redstone repeaters, which need to receive a predictable and non-random tick in the near future.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1sz6.png

- fpslimit_wait

Fills up the rest of the frame render time with waiting, used when you cap your framerate to below what it would normally be.

- preRenderErrors

Couldn't find much on this, and annoyingly I don't have a <kbd>10</kbd> key to check out if it has any sub-sections. Apparently overlapping transparency contributes to it, although I couldn't get it off 0.00%

Comment: No computers have a 10 key so i can't see how you can check preRenderErrors.

Comment: preRenderErrors are most likely rendering errors that happen while loading chunks, but I could be wrong.